# Upgrading to Spark 2.0.1 broke array<string> in parquet DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I have a table with a few columns, some of which are arrays. Since upgrading from Spark 1.6 to Spark 2.0.1, the array fields are always null when reading in a DataFrame.

When writing the Parquet files, the schema of the column is specified as

```
StructField("packageIds",ArrayType(StringType)).
```

The schema of the column in the Hive Metastore is

```
packageIds array<string>
```

The schema used in the writer exactly matches the schema in the Metastore

The query is a simple "select *"

```
spark.sql("select * from tablename limit 1").collect() // null columns in Row
```

How can I debug this issue? Notable things I've already investigated:

- It works in spark 1.6
- I've inspected the parquet files using parquet-tools and can see the data.
- I also have another table written in exactly the same way and it doesn't have the issue.

Comment: Try [dev@spark.apache.org](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/) or https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK/

Comment: Ok good idea.I think user@spark.apache.org is where help emails are meant to be directed. I'll try there.